# Add ONE constraint to several bones?

Tags: bones, constraints

So, I want to add a Limit Rotation constraint with "Limit Z" option checked for many bones at once. Now, I know about the "Copy Constraints" function, BUT in this case, the bones already have other constraints on them (with different targets) which I want to keep, and just Copying all constraints would overwrite these.

How can I add only one constraint to other bones without overwriting existing ones?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I managed to solve it myself now with a Python script, it goes like this:

```
import bpy

for b in bpy.context.selected_pose_bones[:]:
     rot = b.constraints.new(type='LIMIT_ROTATION')
     rot.use_limit_z = True
```

You need to have your bones selected (in pose mode).